# Using requests to download a file results in the webpages html

Tags: python, file, python-requests, download

My code currently is:

```
url = "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1-PopFOwxcm39uW4I-tVM5tSrOjvyOCly&export=download"

# Get all the files from mediafire link

def fetchFilesMedia():
  response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
  with open("test", "wb") as handle:
    for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
        handle.write(data)
```

I want it to download all the folders in the zip but currently it just downloads the webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta name="description" content="Google Drive is a free way to keep your files backed up and easy to reach from any phone, tablet, or computer. Start with 15GB of Google storage – free.">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
  <title>Meet Google Drive – One place for all your files</title>
  <style>
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OUuhs.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

etc.

Comment: If you browse to that URL on your own, does the file automatically download?

Comment: You cannot download a google drive folder with a simple url GET.  It has to be authenticated, if its a protected folder as well as there are some headers to be used. Check this https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python

Comment: @Kris fair enough, ill take a look thanks.